# Controlling ffdshow from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ffdshow

ffdshow has this [awesome little API](http://ffdshow-tryout.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ffdshow-tryout/trunk/src/ffdshowRemoteAPI.cpp?view=markup) for controlling playback of video files. It allows you to change subtitles, fast forward, get the name of the file playing, etc...

Its implemented as a windows message loop that accepts user messages and posts data back using WM_COPYDATA.

I would like a c#/vb class that will allow me to perform all the control. (send and receive messages). I know how to write this. I'll probably create a hidden window hook up a windows message loop and send messages back and forth.

I would like to know if someone has already done this, cause implementing it is a bit fiddly, and this is for an open source project anyway so I have very limited time to work on it.

#### This question remains unanswered, the bounty system chose a wrong answer for this question.

Comment: I've been working on directshow for one of my project. ffdshow was used as a decoder/compressor. For playback control, I rely on directshow's graph event. Never knew ffdshow can also do that, cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin in class has been created and is available here:
http://damienbt.free.fr/Information.htm

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the FFDShow-tryout guys already built a wrapper.  I haven't tested it out (probably tonight), but it looks promising.

[FFDShowAPI at FFDShow's wiki page](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/wiki/devel:controlling?s[]=ffdshowapi)