# How to play non-PCM file or convert it to PCM on the fly ?

Tags: c#, delphi, audio, wav, pcm

The following code works with some wav files, but with others I get, "InvalidOperationException was unhandled. Message=Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files."

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
var fileSound = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
fileSound.PlaySync();
```

Is there a way to programmatically check if a wav file is "bad" (not a PCM wave file) and then convert it as necessary?

What is odd is that the code works in the legacy Delphi app - all of the wav files play just fine. Here's the Delphi code:

```
filename := GetEnvironmentVariable('TEMP')+'\archieAndDingbat.wav';
URLDownloadToFile(nil, PChar(url), PChar(filename), 0, nil);
PlaySound(filename);
```

I looked at the properties of the two files in Explorer, and I see that there is, indeed, a difference. For the file that does play, its audio format is PCM; the one that won't play is CCITT u-Law.

So...I either need a way to convert from CCITT u-Law to PCM on the fly after downloading these files (they are download from an url and then played locally) OR perhaps a different way of playing these files than PlaySync() ...

Comment: What other formats do you expect?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not expecting anything; I thought a .wav file was a .wav file was a .wav file, so was quite perplexed when one played fine and the other didn't.

Comment: Nope, lots of variants of .wav http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to use newkie's code at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175030/PlaySound-A-Better-Way-to-Play-Wav-Files-in-C?msg=4366037#xx4366037xx

In my case, at least, I had to change all of the lowercase x's to uppercase x's, though, to get it to work.

Comment: The 'x's don't have to be uppercased, but they do have to be replaced. (It's some odd unicode 'x')

Answer (score 1):

Look at audiolab library from mitov. It works great

Comment: Okay, I'll czech it out tomorrow.

Comment: Well, now i know the missing verb for "I accidentally" meme :-)

Comment: Mitov seems to be for Embarcadero products only, which is "so 1990s" (at one time I was a Delphi diehard, but that was then...)

Comment: @Clay, hey, Delphi isn't 1990s :-) Few days ago Embarcadero released [`Delphi XE3`](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi).

Comment: @Clay WUT? *Mitov Software offers Delphi, C++ Builder, Visual C++ MFC/Win32 and . NET 2.0-4.0 (C#, Visual Basic, C++/CLI, J#)*
Transparent bridge VCL<->MFC is alone not very borlandish. Neither is .Net novadays.

Comment: DirectX codecs (from http://free-codecs.com for example) used for playback in dot-net via http://mitov.com/products/basicaudio#downloads - what there about "Embarcadero-only" ???

Comment: @TLama: some people still like Disco, too. Not to diss Delphi; I used to love it. It's just not in the same ballpark with the Microsoft tools anymore. In fact, if I was a "betting man," I'd invest (big time) in MS. Maybe not this year or next, but after that I think they're going to put on muscles that would make Clay Matthews look like a 98-lb. weakling.

Answer (score 1):

So, do you want to PLAY the file or CONVERT it ? What is the primary goal ? Do you play it as a prove you can convert it, or do you convert it because you don't know how to play not-converted file ?
http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Your question's title claims "convert" but the body claims "Play"

This answer is about playing files.

---

You also may try to use FFDShow codecs directly without DirectX intermediate.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec and http://libav.org/ and http://ffmpeg.org/ (they recently had a schism)

Googling for "FFDShow dotnet", "libav dotnet", "ffmpeg dotnet" shows a bunch of libraries to use it, such as

- https://github.com/ermau/libav.net
- [Controlling ffdshow from .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245232)
- [Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036)

---

There is also BASS library. It is targeted as sound playback during gaming, so it probably has less range of formats and not much for re-coding. Still many music players are built on top of it. Some says it is the most simple API to use. So it worth considering. http://www.un4seen.com/

---

http://MediaInfo.sf.net is a library (native win32/win64 DLL) allowing to check most multimedia formats content.
I don't know if using tis C or C++ APis is easy from C# side.

Comment: But OP wants to play wave files in C# not in Delphi. Anyway, you don't need to use DSPack wrappers, check out how simply you can [`play a file`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx), so in Delphi you can use just DirectShow headers ;-)

Comment: @TLama According to Henry, those headers are just his DSPack copypasted, and he is very upset for it. He expect EMB just cloned them and would never maintain.

Comment: @TLama Bass has .Net API as well

Comment: "do you want to PLAY the file or CONVERT it" - I would prefer to just play it, but .NET's Soundplayer class requires the .wav file to be a PCM .wav file, and refuses to play CCITT u-Law .wav files. So, if there's no way to directly play the CCITT u-Law .wav files, I will need to convert them on the fly from CCITT u-Law to PCM .wav file format.

Comment: IOW, all I want to do is play the file; I don't care how, just as long as it works, the code/library is free or open source - the less muss and fuss the better.

Comment: as to https://github.com/ermau/libav.net, I can't make heads or tails of what it is supposed to be/do. I've never head of FFmpeg before. All I want to do is play a .wav file of the CCITT u-Law dialect. I find it hard to believe there's not a rather straightforward way to either play such a file, or at least to convert the file to the PCM dialect (at which point I can play it with my existing code).

Comment: Clay, try BASS. Dunno about .Net but in Delphi it is simple and reliable. ffmpeg is a complex combine, perhaps too complex for you. BASS is usually liked for simplicity, give it a try. Also you may try Mitov's BasicAudio, though it relies on DirectX which sometimes is fragile (BASS is self-contained).

Comment: ffmpeg/libav is a greatest independent library about video and audio formats, probably the only full-scale competitor to DirectX and GStreamer.  But it probably can be too complex for your needs. However seeing how many .Net wrappers are in the wild for it - i guess many devels find it vlauable after all. PS. i rephrased your question title, ESR's essay will hint you why. Sorry to say, but original title was kind of misleading.