# Is there a way to play a CCITT u-Law .wav file in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, wav, pcm

Having failed to find a way to programmatically convert a CCITT u-Law wave file to a PCM file (which Soundplayer demands) in accord with this question: [How to play non-PCM file or convert it to PCM on the fly ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393707/can-i-convert-an-audio-file-on-the-fly)

(SOX looks like it might work, but I can't find any examples for converting from CCITT u-Law .wav file to a "regular" (PCM) .wav file using it from C#),

I wonder if I'm going about it the wrong way: maybe I should find a way to play CCITT u-Law .wav files, rather than trying to convert such to a PCM .wav file.

Does anybody know how this is possible? SoundPlayer always says, "*Sound API only supports playing PCM wave files*" so maybe there's another API I can use?

Note: Alvas.Audio is also "not an option" due to it not being free or open source.

Comment: This library claims to support it: http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx

Comment: @TJD: alvas.audio may work but, as I mentioned, it costs money, and my employer won't pay for it.

Comment: @Bjorn: I haven't found any reference on how to do it in libsndfile, either - I think it can convert between mp3 and wav, and between aiff and wav, but I didn't see any conversion between wav/pcm and wav/ccitt u-law.

Comment: Whoever pushed the Antarctic button should explain why.

Comment: Just try libsndfile: it has utilities to convert and play any format it can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to use newkie's code at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175030/PlaySound-A-Better-Way-to-Play-Wav-Files-in-C?msg=4366037#xx4366037xx

In my case, at least, I had to change all of the lowercase x's to uppercase x's, though, to get it to work.